# Why were some BIPs marked as Rejected before expiry deadline defined in BIP-2?

Tags: bip

[BIP-2](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0002.mediawiki) says:

> BIPs should be changed from Draft or Proposed status, to Rejected status, upon request by any person, if they have not made progress in three years.

However, some BIPs were marked as Rejected earlier than 3 years after their last commit. Examples include [BIP-140](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/commits/master/bip-0140.mediawiki) (last commit before it was marked as Rejected in September 2017 / rejected in June 2020) and [BIP-156](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/commits/master/bip-0156.mediawiki) (August 2018 / June 2020). Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these were both just minor oversights. The [first example](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/commits/master/bip-0140.mediawiki) you link to (BIP 140) was moved to Rejected status approximately 3 months early. The [second example](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/commits/master/bip-0156.mediawiki) (BIP 156) was moved to Rejected status 3 years after it was created but 2 years since the most recent commit. However, with Dandelion it wasn't just the 3 year rejection rule being considered, it seems there were also other reasons to reject the proposal. The related Bitcoin Core [pull request](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/13947#issuecomment-513858189) was closed due to DoS concerns.

There have been [discussions](https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/bitcoin-dev/2021-September/019469.html) to ditch the 3 year rejection rule entirely in a proposed BIP process update (i.e. BIP 3) but currently BIP 2 contains this 3 year rejection rule.